# noobie question on 3 phase

Tags: phase

i am renovating a house and the electrician has installed all new wiring ,circuit switches, outlets etc...  so now the electric company has asked if i want 1 or 3 phase.  I told them 3 phase and already paid for that but now i am worried that the wiring already done might be incompatible with 3 phase.  excuse my ignorance but i never could really understand how electricity works.
my old system was on a 5 amp meter and it was a given that i would change the meter to 15 amps--so the new wiring is up to spec--   can someone guide me a little on this.  by the way this is in northern thailand

Comment: You should really talk to the electrician and see how he/she wired it. The different methods are NOT compatible, and it will probably cost more to have the power company change things _after_ the installation...

Answer (score 3):

Most of the wiring will be single phase anyway.  Small loads are only intended to run on one phase.

But you need to check with your electrician whether the main consumer unit (fuse board) is a single phase or three phase one.  If it's a single phase one, you will only be able to use one of the three phases.

Comment: i will assume that the main fuse board is single phase--then can i assume that if i get 3 phase input i can still use my electricity--albeit can only use one of the 3 phases. ?  no additional wiring to use just one of the phases?

Comment: @asiaexpat If it's a single phase board, then you will only be able to connect one of the phases.  The other two will just have to be left disconnected.  But it should be fairly obvious when you come to do the connection which it is - don't just assume anything.  A 3-phase board will have three live/hot/phase inputs and a neutral going into the main switch.  A single phase one will only have one live/hot/phase terminal.

Comment: well it turned out i am only getting single phase and money already refunded--case closed--thanx for all your comments

Answer (score 3):

As Simon B wrote, your "daily usage" tools are normally only using one phase, except for high-power loads or some powerful workshop tools (table saw for example). Workshop tools also use 3-phase because their motors depend on the rotating magnetic field you can easily generate using three-phase power.

A high power load for daily usage may be an electrical kitchen stove, here in Germany it consumes usually roundabout 9-13 kilo Watts when connected to a three-phase outlet. But there exist also versions that can connect to one or three phase. If they are connected to one phase, they consume less power and hence are not that powerful. But since I'm writing from Germany, there WILL be differences to your country.

Nevertheless, a three-phase supply to your home is never a bad thing, because the electrician can distribute your outlets to the three phases, or can connect an high-power electrical stove to it.

Also in case of an outage of individual phases (wires) the others remain live and can power parts of your home (in case your company provides a neutral wire).

But... to make it "short" :D :

If northern thailand also uses a system like we have it in Germany, your electric company will provide four wires to you / your main panel: L1, L2, L3 and N, where the L (live) wires "conduct" the individual phases and the N is the neutral wire that closes the circuit for 1-phase devices or non-symmetrical loads.

Also some systems use a PE (protective earth) which is connected to a metal pole or a similar structure that is rammed into the earth next to your home, for security reasons.

Inside the main panel, the electrician connects high power devices or the corresponding breakers/outlets to all three phases L1-3 (and sometimes to N, if the device can not be considered to be "symmetrical") and PE.

The usual loads like your lights, normal wall outlets, fridges, dishwashers etc. are connected to one of the three phase wires, the neutral and PE.

This is the reason why three phase devices have a plug with five poles (L1, L2, L3, N and PE) and single-phase devices have a plug with three poles (L1 for example, N and PE).

A side-note: Devices that are connected between one L and N will receive 230V, devices that are connected between two L-conductors will receive 400V. The first one is called Y-configuration, the second one is called delta-configuration. Hence it is **very** important that the outlets/devices are connected properly. (If it is connected the wrong way, your devices will have super-powers, but only for a very short period ;).)

But seriously: That is one of the benefits of the three-phase system. You get two voltages with the same three wires, just by connecting them in a different way. That is used for example to provide a "soft start" feature for big motors. They start in Y-configuration with low-power at a low voltage. As soon as the motor is spinning some contactors are re-configured such that the motor is attached in a delta configuration, getting the full 400V and hence having the full power.

Long answer short: Your wiring, if you have at least two (better three, one for PE) wires that run to each outlet/lamp, is completely compatible to a three phase system that your electrical company provides to you. The single phase devices just use only one out of the three phases.

Also, you can have a look at [this website on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-phase_electric_power) if you are curious. Wikipedia does not always contain correct information, but for a first introduction it's never wrong. They also provide some animations.

A hint: If possible for you / applicable to your system (ask your electrician of trust first) install a whole-house (not only for the bathroom) GFCI/RCD breaker ([click here for a wiki article!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual-current_device)) in addition to your circuit breakers.

This GFCI will protect you from getting an electrical shock in case there is a fault in a device. If possible, better install individual GFCIs for each level of your house and for the fridges. If one device has a fault, your food in your fridge will not get warm ;).

A simple circuit breaker **does not** protect you from getting an electrical shock, it only protects the wires from getting too hot in case of a short circuit.

Somehow a "disclaimer":

1)
Be aware, that AC power is able to mess up your heartbeat and hence kill you. Do not do electrical work on your own except if you are a trained professional. Also a wrong installation can cause a fire, some insurances do not pay afterwards if the installation was not performed by a certified professional. I know ... [Homer Simpson] "Booooring" :D.

2)
I was talking about the three-phase three-wire system. There exist also systems that can be called one-phase three-wire systems that have three wires which all are "in phase", which means their voltage maxima are in sync. In a three-phase three-wire system the voltage maxima occur one after the other, shifted by 120°.

3)
I'm talking about the German system, Thailand may/will have a different one.

I know that this answer may be a bit tooo technical and way too long, but I tried to explain it as short and informative as possible...but short is really a matter of taste :D

Comment: thats a great post and I will spend some time trying to understand it.  All work is not being done by me. the way the electrician did it is circuits split up by--outlets,light switches,aircon,hot shower machine, and one circuit for my crypto miner, and one for outside water pump--there is also grounding-all outlet plugs are 3 pronged with ground

Comment: Thank you :) If in doubt, ask ;) ... sounds good. By the way: I like the fact that you have a dedicated circuit for your miner :D .... that's enthusiastic :D